# Importing XML values into MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I have a script running as cron which is importing values into mysql from an xml document like:

```
$dbl1= $xml->xml1;
$dbl2= $xml->xml2;
$dbl3= $xml->xml3;
$dbl4= $xml->xml4;
```

from an xml like:

```
<xml1>content</xml1>
<xml2>content</xml2>
<xml3>content</xml3>
<xml4>content</xml4>
```

This is all working great but I have a field like the following in the xml file and I want to know how to correctly import just the cost qualifier eg:

```
<cost qualifier="Full Value" currency="GBP" display="yes">3000</cost>
```

I can get the 3000 cost value but not the qualifier?

Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it! Just needed the following:

```
$dbl4= $xml->cost[qualifier];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
You may make use of the SimpleXMLElement::attributes function.
To get reference, you may refer to the following code as an example : 

$xml = simplexml_load_string($string);
foreach($xml->cost[0]->attributes() as $a => $b) {
    echo $a,'="',$b,"\"\n";
}
It will get you print you the value of qualifier, currency and display attributes of cost
```